# 英語が残っている：コミュニティをさらに表示：スタック・オーバーフロー

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: ja.so]

> For プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人.

ポルトガル版に比べたら、全文が翻訳されています

[image: pt.so]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

修正案：プログラマーおよびプログラミングに熱心な人向け。